# Tranfer data from local table to linked server object's table on condition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have configured a linked server object "DIS" on my system for accessing remote database. I am accessing it by using code segment [DIS].[DISTemp].[dbo].[Agency].

I have a table tbBroker on my local database. Now I have to transfer data from my local machine's tbBroker to DIS's table Agency. The columns in the both tables are mapped as follows

```
    tbBroker's Columns  -  Agency's Columns
    BrokerCode          -  AgencyNumber
    BusinesssName       -  AgencyName
    City                -  City
    Email               -  EmailAddress
```

Now I have to transfer data from local machine to DIS on the basis of condition.

Check if agency is present in [Agency] table of DIS. Use BrokerCode from tbBroker(from local machine) to validate.

- If Exists

  Update record in DIS's Agency Table.
- If Doesn’t Exists

  Insert record in DIS's Agency table.

[image]

Please help me !!!

Comment: you may need to provide some sample data,Others may have hard time understanding the mappings between agency,broker which may be simple for you

Comment: Please add details of the two different database collations in your question.

Comment: After adding ON
  [TARGET].[AgencyNumber] = [SOURCE].[BrokerCode] COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI... Now it does not show collate  issue but it throws The target of a MERGE statement cannot be a remote table, a remote view, or a view over remote tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given what I understand from your question, I think you are best using a [`MERGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb510625.aspx) statement.

As you cannot set the target of a `MERGE` as a remote table, the following will need to be executed on the remote database, linking back to the source.

```
USE [DISTemp];

MERGE INTO
  [dbo].[Agency] AS [TARGET]
USING
  [<<sourceDB>>].[dbo].[tbBroker] AS [SOURCE]
ON
  [TARGET].[AgencyNumber] = [SOURCE].[BrokerCode]
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
  INSERT (    
    [AgencyNumber]
  , [AgencyName]
  , [WebsiteUrl]
  , [City]
  , [EmailAddress]  
  )
  VALUES (
    [SOURCE].[BrokerCode]
  , [SOURCE].[BusinesssName]
  , [SOURCE].[WebsiteUrl]
  , [SOURCE].[City]
  , [SOURCE].[Email]
  )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET
    [TARGET] = [AgencyNumber] = [SOURCE].[BrokerCode]
  , [TARGET] = [AgencyName]   = [SOURCE].[BusinesssName]
  , [TARGET] = [WebsiteUrl]   = [SOURCE].[WebsiteUrl]
  , [TARGET] = [City]         = [SOURCE].[City]
  , [TARGET] = [EmailAddress] = [SOURCE].[Email];
```

Comment: This solution sounds good.. but it throws Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AI" in the equal to operation.

Comment: That's because you have different collations set on your databases. Add `[TARGET].[AgencyNumber] = [SOURCE].[BrokerCode] COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI` to the line.

Comment: Fix your database collation issues and the `MERGE` statement will work.

Comment: I have resolved collate issue....  Now it is throwing... The target of a MERGE statement cannot be a remote table, a remote view, or a view over remote tables. Can you please provide another query method

Comment: You'll need to execute the MERGE on the target database. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Great Solution... Thanks